# put an attribute on an html tag using an * ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm doing an app using IONIC, but it's based on angular. I simply want that if one element is the last one:

```
(item==myArray.length?'navPop':'')
```

add the **navPop** attribute, otherwise do not add it. (in IONIC, navPop attribute is, when you click, it returns to a preview that is what I need).

I'm doing this, but I get errors:

```
this.myArray=[1,2,3,4];

<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of myArray" text-center item==myArray.length?'navPop':''>
```

I hope this result (if is my last element):

```
<ion-slide text-center></ion-slide>
<ion-slide text-center></ion-slide>
<ion-slide text-center></ion-slide>
//last element with navPop
<ion-slide text-center navPop></ion-slide>
```

how can I fix it, thanks?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `attr` binding, like so:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of myArray" text-center [attr.navPop]="item==myArray.length ? '': null" >
```

You could also modify this to use the `last` property, as suggested by others

Answer (score 2):

Use last

```
 <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of myArray;let _last=last" text-center [attr.navPop]="_last" >
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

`index: number: The index of the current item in the iterable.` 
`first: boolean: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.`
`last: boolean: True when the item is the last item in the iterable.`
`even: boolean: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.`
`odd: boolean: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do following. Angular provides a variable called `last` within `ngFor`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of myArray; let isLast = last">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLast"> 
         <ion-slide text-center></ion-slide>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLast"> 
         <ion-slide text-center navPop></ion-slide>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```